# Regex removes to much text

Tags: c#, regex

In our CMS we are using some tags which should be replaced on exporting for other systems.

The code for replacing is stated below:

```
 var rxStr = "<div[^<]+class=([\"'])related-document-content\\1.*</div>";
 var rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(rxStr,
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 bodyText = rx.Replace(bodyText, "");
```

Our problem occurs when there are to instances of the tag in rxStr :

```
<p>First paragraph</p>
<div class='related-document-content' id='457'>First related text</div>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<div class='related-document-content' id='458'>Second related text</div>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
```

When the code runs it removes the second paragraph and the output will be

```
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
```

Can anyone help me adjust code so that only the div tags get removed

Comment: You should be using an html parser for this... JMHO

Comment: Try making it non greedy `.*?` instead of `.*`

Comment: Never use Regex on HTML or XML.  They are not regular and using native libraries are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the obvious "Use an HTML parser/write instead":

What your regex matches is the `<` of the next HTML tag over, that's why it skips one.
Your `rxStr` looks for "anything but the next open tag" `<div[^<]+`.

Instead it should look for "anything but the current tag's end" `<div[^>]+`.
You then also add the `>` to your regular expression. See below:

```
// Added [^>]+> towards the end.
// Also adding () within the div so you can debug better which matches were found.
var rxStr = "<div[^>]+class=([\"'])related-document-content\\1[^>]*>(.*)</div>";
```

If the innerHTML of your div is actually text-only use `[^<]*` instead of `.*`:

```
var rxStr = "<div[^>]+class=([\"'])related-document-content\\1[^>]*>([^<]*)</div>";
```